# How can I make my werewolf claws more effective?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I'm having a little bit of a dilema over here:

I love the ability to turn into a werewolf and chase people down, but my claws don't seem to do much damage (especially compared to my 2 handed weapon).   How can do more damage as a werewolf making my nightly pillages more terrifying?

Comment: Possibly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36263/6914

Comment: Play a khajit? They get an unarmed bonus.

Comment: @Raven is the werewolf's attack considered 'unarmed'?

Comment: Hard to test, considering there's no longer an "unarmed" skill.

Comment: I don't believe you can increase the damage. I usually just use werewolf for its fast CC power attack, which counters the low damage.

Comment: Note: the new DLC, Dawnguard, will give a "Werewolf" branch in the skill tree, letting you improve further.

Comment: @Arkive that link isn't duplicate. The link mentions a khajiit while this question mentions a werewolf.

Answer (score 6):

To all viewing this recently. .

As A.C.M. noted, claw damage increases with character level but is not on a scale with damage from actual weapons.  You will have 0 armor as a werewolf, so the damage output will not keep you alive.  The fear roar does not work on higher level opponents; even bandits are immune at higher levels!

Essentially, after approximately level 30, werewolves are generally useless except for the disease immunity, which sometimes doesn't work anyway.  The ability to carry large amts of gear is offset by their being unable to pick up gear, so it is of reduced usefulness.  Sprinting is the only advantage and pretty much pointless in a game with fast travel.

Final answer:  use a mod someone has made, mod the game yourself, or don't transform, since nearly everything can 1-shot you around lvl 30 or so.

Comment: Dawnguard changes things for Werewolves significantly. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Werewolf see the 'Skill Perks' section to see the changes, including perks that increase damage dealt (up to 100% extra damage)

Answer (score 3):

The khajit racial attribute of +15 to unarmed attacks will not stack with the werewolf claws. The werewolf is considered a seperate race - and all racial skills and attributes are lost in werewolf form.

I have however heard that the game engine treats the werewolf claw attack as a single handed weapon, and that the dual savagery perk effects the claw attack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're an orc you can cast berserker rage right before transforming. So you will deal twice as much damage. You can glitch where you wield weapons in your hands after transformation. I usually go under water dual wielding weapons (usually enchanted so I maintain those effects) to make this bug occur. With Dawnguard installed the first werewolf perks increases your damage by 25% each rank up to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

To do more damage as a werewolf you need to increase your level. The damage your claws do is separated into level brackets.e.x.lvl -20 = 20dam lvl 20-30 = 30dam etc. (note these are not actual values they are just an example Ill find actual levels and damage and get back to you) but unfortunately the damage doesnt get very higher and more often then not you will do more damage as a human.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to make your claw attacks stronger but it is technically considered a bug.

If you are dual wielding enchanted weapons when you transform into a werewolf, the enchantments will stay on your claws.

This is a great way to increase damage output as a werewolf but could be considered an exploit.

Comment: Fire claws here I come!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing about werewolves. They are incredibly fun to play if done right. Mines level 34 and here or some of the things I did.

You can start at as any race, but it helps to be a race with a elemental resistance, i.e. Nord, breton etc. Breton works best imho. 25% magic resist + lord stone + alteration perk magic resistance + agent of mara = 95% magic resist. From what I read the magic resist cap is 97. Pretty good if you ask me.

Now for physical defense, put perks in alteration all the way up to stability and expert and use Ebonyflesh. Since the werewolf is considered unarmored, casting ebonyflesh + the mage armor perk + lord stone gives you 350 armor. Granted thats still about 200 armor under the damage cap of 567 (I think its 567, may be 587), put remember that just because you are a monster doesnt mean you are a tank. Remember that there are some effects that carry over from regular form to werewolf form, like the Orcs berserker trait.

note* You could also use dragonskin to meet the 80% damage cap for physical attacks but its only for 30 seconds. Dual casting ebonyflesh makes the length stay on for 90 seconds. Depends on what you want I suppose.

The claw damage scale doesnt compare well in later levels with actual weapons, but the advantage the Werewolf form does have is an extra 100 stamina and killer knockback effects that work on all but the biggest enemies. This allows you to fight dragon priests and draugr high levels pretty easily because of the ability to use power attacks.

I have done all this on mine and I am loving it. I should also note that go ahead and level an armor tree and weapon tree as well just in case there are times that transforming wouldnt be the best choice. I have had a few of those but they are extremely rare, for what I have done at least.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  You've explained how to play a werewolf, but that's not what's been asked for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dlc and improve your bestial strength and acquire the totems, especially the totems of brotherhood, you can kill even the toughest enemies including dragons, dragon preists, draugr, and bandits within seconds with the power attacks and summoned wolves/werewolves.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to make the claws stronger but I know you can stack spells on top of your werewolf. I am an ORC and before I transform into my werewolf I use the Dragon aspect shout, any cloak spell, Ebony Flesh, Dragon hide and berserk rage and also some perks do transfer over such as Atronach allows you to absorb 30% of magic thrown at you you can also get the Atronach stone or Lord stone for added bonus and then there are the rings for the werewolf which you can buy in the Dragonborn DLC.
I hope this helps.